# List of MVC Ajax links only update page once

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of Ajax links that are created by the code below.
It displays a name with a link "remove" next to it.
When clicked, I want the name/link removed from the list.

Problem: I can only click and update the page once.
After clicking one of the Ajax links which removes it from the list,
it won't let me click another link. I click and it doesn't do anything.
If I want to click and remove another link, I have to refresh the page.

I don't really know javascript but I'm guessing it has to do with the name or id of the element being the same.

```
    <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4" border="1" width="750">


        @foreach (var item2 in Model.PeopleCheckBoxes) 
        {
            if (ctr == 3)
            {
                @:<tr>
            }
            <td><img  src="icon.jpg">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="middle" align="left">

              @item2.Username

             @item2.Username &nbsp; &nbsp;
            @Ajax.ActionLink("remove", "RemoveMemberFromEvent", "GiftList", 
                             new { eventID = @Model.catID, peopleID = @item2.Id },
                     new AjaxOptions
                        {
                        UpdateTargetId = "peopleTable",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                        }, new { @class = "details2", title = "Remove person" })    
                        </td>
            if (ctr == 5)
            {
                @:</tr>
                ctr = 2;
            }
            ctr++;

        } </table>
```

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RemoveMemberFromEvent(int eventID, int peopleID) 
{
    // removes item :
    var aEvent = (from p in _EventMemberRepository.Table
    // ............
    _giftListService.DeletePersonOnGiftPage(aEvent);

    // then update the database :
    var members2 = from c in _custRepository.Table
    var vModel = new GiftListItems();
    //...........

    return PartialView("_RemoveMemberFromEvent", vModel); 
}
```

Is this a common problem?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a checkbox + submit button approach. Especially since you `don't really know javascript`, you'll save yourself a huge headache

Comment: "checkbox + submit button approach" . .  you mean a regular form without Ajax?

Comment: Yeah.  Your action would take a list of people, and if `ToRemove` was checked, it could knock them out